# Komplexere Sätze schreiben

Tags: style

Die Frage mag einigen bescheuert vorkommen, vor allem weil es bei vielen Leuten verpönt ist, mit Absicht komplexer (nicht unbedingt komplizierter) zu schreiben, als es nötig wäre, aber ich muss öfters Hausarbeiten für meine Uni schreiben und es kommt mir vor, als wären meine Sätze viel zu simpel.
Ich habe schon ein bisschen im Internet gesucht, dort aber nicht viel gefunden.

Gibt es einige typische Schemata oder Satzstrukturen, die komplexe Sätze charakterisieren? Wie gesagt, ich meine nicht unbedingt kompliziert, sondern einfach komplex.

Ich lese auch oft wissenschaftliche Literatur, in der komplexe Satzstrukturen vorkommen, aber ich lerne diese nicht extra auswendig, das wäre mir auch bisschen zu blöde.
Edit: Zusätzlich muss ich dazu sagen, dass ich mich erst seit meinem Studienbeginn wirklich mit korrekter Rechtschreibung und Kommasetzung beschäftigt habe, jetzt muss ich an meinem Stil arbeiten.

Comment: Im Englischen nimmt nimmt man heutzutage an, ein Text sei umso besser, je einfacher er zu verstehen ist. Im Deutschen scheint man traditionell davon auszugehen, dass es wenn es "schwer zu schreiben" war auch "schwer zu lesen" sein muss. Das ist ziemlich schade, weil es einfach nicht stimmt. Ich würde mir über die mangelnde Komplexität deiner Formulierungen erstmal keine Sorgen machen.

Comment: Hallo. Danke für deinen Kommentar. Ja ich weiß, aber meine Sätze sollen nicht komplizierter sein, sondern eher komplexer. Ich weiß, dass das verpöhnt ist, aber die Realität sieht das leider etwas anders aus. Ein Dozent von mir meinte letztens noch, dass er eine Arbeit geschrieben hat, in der er möglichst verklausuliert einen anderen Wissenschaftlicher kritisiert hat. Ist wohl ein typisch deutsches Phänomen.

Comment: Du darfst damit anfangen, "verpönt" erstmal ohne "h" zu schreiben ;) (Nur, weil ich's oben schon korrigiert habe)

Comment: Meinst du so etwas: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/46512/general-rule-for-translation-of-german-participle-constructions

Comment: Bewahre dir die Fähigkeit, komplexe Sachverhalte in einfachen Sätzen darzustellen, davon hast du in deinem weiteren Leben viel mehr, als das Gegenteil zu versuchen!

Comment: @IQV  Oder vielleicht so? - Schreibe verständlich! Komplexe Dinge einfach darzustellen ist ein Kunst. Beherrscht du sie, werden deine Leser dich lieben.

Comment: Im universitären Bereich ist es tatsächlich offenbar immer noch üblich, sich langatmig auszudrücken, das gilt wohl als Zeichen für "Tiefe". Im journalistischen Bereich sieht das anders aus. Mir berichtete mal jemand, ein Text mit kurzen Sätzen sei an einer Universität als "zu journalistisch" kritisiert worden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guter Rat ist hier billig:

Du sollst auch in wissenschaftlichen Arbeiten auf einen guten, verständlichen Stil achten. Das heißt aber nicht unbedingt kurze Sätze. Sprache ist auch Rhythmus. Ein Text soll rhythmisch in sich stimmig sein. Hat er nur kurze Sätze, wirkt er kurzatmig. Wie dieser hier.

Allerdings leiden wissenschaftliche Texte selten unter solcher Kurzatmigkeit. Eher im Gegenteil. Der Grund ist: Oftmals ist in wissenschaftlichen Zusammmenhängen der Inhalt so komplex, dass sich daraus praktisch automatisch schon kompliziertere Sätze ergeben, schon alleine deswegen, weil man sich beim wissenschaftlichen Schreiben vor allem um Präzision und Unanfechtbarkeit bemüht, und das ist oft nur erreichbar durch Einflechten relativierender Ergänzungen im Satz.

Die meisten wissenschaftlichen Schreiber werden sich folglich eher bemühen müssen, ihre Ausdrucksweise leichtfüssiger zu machen. Künstlich komplizierter macht kein ernsthaft Schreibender seine Sätze (außer vielleicht ein Humorist).

Das nach meiner Meinung beste Buch für guten Stil im Deutschen ist:

- Ludwig Reiners: Die Stilfibel. Der sichere Weg zum guten Deutsch. - Buch erschienen 1950 in München, danach vielfach neu aufgelegt.

Du findest es heute noch im Neubuchhandel, kannst aber auch für Einsfünfzig eine gebrauchte Ausgabe ergattern (probier mal www.booklooker.de). Das Buch bietet jede Menge (oft amüsanter) Beispiele für schlechtes Deutsch, sortiert nach Kategorien des Schlechten; es zeigt dann, wie man die Dinge besser ausdrücken kann; und es gibt Übungen zum Selberausprobieren. Das ist nicht speziell auf wissenschaftliches Schreiben gemünzt, aber die Grundsätze sind universell: Sie gelten weitgehend auch in der Wissenschaft.

Wichtig ist vor allem - und das wird dann auch in die Notengebung an deiner Universität eingehen - dass du das für dein Fach spezifische Vokabular richtig einsetzt. (Das Vokabular ist dabei aber auch wieder nur das Oberflächensymptom, an dem man meint, dein Verständnis der zugrundeliegenden Konzepte zu erkennen.)

Comment: +1 für den Hinweis auf den Gebrauch fachspezifischen Vokabulars

Comment: Danke sehr ! Ich werde mir das Buch auf jeden Fall ansehen.

Answer (score 7):

> Für den gleichbleibend verschwurbelten, der wissenschaftlichen Güte, obwohl schwer beweisbar, angemessenen Ausdruck ist die ständige und reichliche Nutzung von Partizipialkonstruktionen, welche durch gelegentlich auch unsinningen Gebrauch von Relativsätzen weiter unverständlich, den Gedankengang in Leere laufen lassend, werden, unerlässlich.

Comment: Haha ok. Danke für diesen Beispielsatz.